# How to find out the HDMI version supported

Tags: nvidia, hdmi, external-monitor

How can I find out which HDMI version the laptop supports, in particular if it is HDMI 1.3?

---

Full story:

I'm considering acquiring either a `Dell U2414H` or `Dell U2515H`/`Dell U2715H` (or similar) capable of resolutions of respectively 1920x1080 and 2560x1440. This is for an old laptop with an nvidia 9600M GT, which supposedly can handle a resolution of up to `2560x1600`.

Since the laptop only comes with VGA and HDMI, I'll be using the HDMI port. It seems that to support the resolution of `2560x1440` of the larger monitor I'd need to have HDMI version 1.3; HDMI 1.2 only supports resolutions of up to `1920x1080`.¹ This mean that with HDMI 1.3 I can buy the 27-inch monitor, otherwise I'm better of with the 24-inch one.

¹ I suspect the laptop doesn't support HDMI 1.4 because it got out around the time it was bought. Checked it on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Version_comparison).

Comment: Apparently this was helpful to at least 3 people...  Why didn't you ever accept the answer?

Comment: "Apparently this was helpful to at least 3 people... Why didn't you ever accept the answer?" -- The answer is helpful but doesn't answer the question. To give you an example, I have a laptop from 2015 which only supports HDMI 1.4 even though HDMI 2.0 was out in 2013. Interestingly, this laptop can only output Full HD even though the graphics card supports higher resolutions; I was told this has to do with internal wiring. So even though it has a graphics card capable of 2160p and HDMI 1.4, I'm not getting more than 1080p out of it.

Comment: The "faulty" wiring *is* the HDMI circuit.  **:-/**

Comment: Getting lots of upvotes on the answer in the meantime with no other answers...  Still no acceptance? **;-)**

Answer (score 5):

You cannot probe this information directly, but you can infer it.  Below all HDMI versions:

```
HDMI version    1               1.1             1.2             1.3             1.4             2
Date released:  9 Dec 2002      20 May 2004     8 Aug 2005      22 Jun 2006     28 May 2009     4 Sep 2013
Max resolution  1920×1200p60    1920×1200p60    1920×1200p60    2560×1600p60    4096×2160p30    4096×2160p60
```

[<sub>Source</sub>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Version_comparison)

**So you can be sure you've got 1.3!**